# Construction of std::string fails

Tags: c++, string, stl

I am afraid it is a really stupid question but I do not get it. I'm contructing a `std::string` that contains a line feed (needed for further processing) this way:

```
std::string mystr=std::string("\n")
```

Amazingly `mystr` is empty afterwards. And when I step into the string-constructor the handed over data are empty too (so no `\n` contained). What is wrong here?

Comment: Why don't you just use `std::string mystr = "\n"`?

Comment: http://ideone.com/tHTWLJ

Comment: You could also use `std::endl`

Comment: The character `\n` is a newline character, not a line feed. `\r` is a line feed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string should not be empty, it should have size `1`. What leads you to believe it is empty?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string s1 = std::string("\n");
  std::string s2;
  std::cout << s1.size() << "\n";
  std::cout << s2.size() << "\n";
}
```

output `1` and `0`.

What could be confusing you is a copy elision or a move construction in this expression:

```
std::string s1 = std::string("\n");
```

which one would normally write like this anyway:

```
std::string s1("\n");
```